# Is it possible to create a textbox wherever the mouse is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsf

Let say that I have an enclosed region (like a `div` region), and within that region, I want at runtime generate a textbox at the exact location of mouse clicked, and each newly created textbox will bind to a value in my managed bean. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, I won't write the exact code, but this should get you started:

Let's divide the problem into three parts:

1. Capture the click event, and send the data to the server
2. Process the data
3. Display the component

**Capture the click event, and send the data to the server**

To capture the event use [`$('mydivSelector').click(function(event))`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), use the div's [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/offset/), and the [`event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)'s pageX, pageY property to calculate the relative position of the click event.

To send it to the server create a hidden form with two hidden inputs. In the javascript event handler ( `.click(function(event))` ) set the value of these inputs to the event's x,y coordinates, and submit the form. To easiest way to set the values is to give them a unique class and use the `$('.uniqueClass')` selector. Using the jsf inputs' ids is the harder way, because you will have to obtain the clientId of the components (see how to do this in [JSF 1.2](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/02/jsf-working-with-component-ids.html), and in [JSF 2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-20-clientid-jquery?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20javalobby/frontpage%20%28Javalobby%20/%20Java%20Zone%29)).

**Process the data**

In your JSF actionListener you will have the coordinates of the javascript click event relative to the div. Create an object holding these and the input field's value (that you want create). Put them in a list.

**Display the component**

You will need to set the div's css to `position:relative;`, and the inputs' css to `position:absolute;`, so the inputs will be positioned relative to the div.

Iterate through this list with `ui:repeat`, create a JSF input field for each one and set the `style` attribute to `top:#{myObject.y}; left:#{myObject.x};`.

**Update:**

UI example for the form, note that depending on the component library, JSF implementation you use there may be better solutions:

JSF:

```
<h:form styleClass="hidden">
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.newInputXCoordinate}" styleClass="xCoordinate" />
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.newInputYCoordinate}" styleClass="yCoordinate" />
    <h:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.createNewInput}" value="Create new input" styleClass="createNewInput"/>
</h:form>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

In the JS set the inputs' value, click on the button.

Comment: thank you. I will try to write some code. I will ask if I have more question.

Comment: Hi, I re-read your post couples times, write some samples codes to understand `offset`, `click` event, `position:absolute` nested in `position:relative`, but I am still puzzle how to send data to the server side. Do I send it to a servlet, a managed bean? can u write some code to illustrate it a bit more please. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example (using a managed bean).

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion. I was able to achieve what I want. I now able to create a textbox wherever i click. One thing I want to ask is how do I put focus on the newly created textbox. So I send the new coordinate to the server, from that coordinate, create a new textbox object and add that to a list, at the same time reload the component that display a list `ui:repeat`. How do I put focus on the newly created text box?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `p:commandLink` has an oncomplete attribute, that will execute js when the ajax call is complete. Find the newly created input with jQuery (should be the last one in the `ui:repeat`'s container), and use jQuery's `focus()`.

Comment: is there a way to keep track of number of element in ui:repeat on the client side?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("targetDivId").click(function(event) {
  $(event.target).append(
     $('<div></div>').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: event.pageX,
        top: event.pageY
     }).append('<input type="text" />'));
});
```

Comment: That will generated a textbox inside the `div` region, but how do I generate that textbox at the location of mouse click?

Comment: Updated answer to account for positioning.

Comment: thank you. I will try to write some code. I will ask if I have more question.

Answer (score 1):

You mean [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/s3mrp/)?

```js
$('a').click(function() {
    $('form').show();
});
```

```css
form { display: none; }
```

```html
<div>
<a href="#">Add Comment</a>
<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="la">label</label>
    <textarea id="l1" name="Name" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Continue &rarr;"></p>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you, however, I do know how to do that? I wonder if I can generate a textbox at runtime at the exact location of the mouse click. Is it possible